# Custom locales position in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, i18next

I'm using i18n translation for my project,
by default the root will be like this

```js
https://example.com/en/business/transaction
```

can I custom the root to like this

```js
https://example.com/business/en/transacation
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Next.js Framework, but what you could do is, that you deploy your application directly to the subfolder `business`. From there, the Next.js service could start and interprets the `https://example.com/business` as  root.

You can see [here, how to set a base directory in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67210569/5508719), in order to set a new root location.